# Remove line drawn on view

Tags: ios, swift2, core-graphics

I am new to CoreGraphics . I am trying to create view which contains two UIImageview added in scrollview programatically. After adding it i want to connect both center with line. I have used bezier path as well as CAShapelayer. But line is drawn on UIImageview also so i want to remove line above UIImageview or send line to back to UIImageview. I have done below code.

```
  let path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(personalProfile.center.x, personalProfile.center.y))
    path.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(vwTwo.center.x, vwTwo.center.y))

    let shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    self.scrollView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Please also check screenshot, i want to remove red marked portion of blue line .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can do this simply by reducing the `zPosition` of your `shapeLayer`

This will allow the layer to be drawn underneath your two views (and far easier than trying to calculate a new start and end point of your line). If you [look at the documentation for `zPosition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/zPosition):

> The default value of this property is 0. Changing the value of this property changes the the front-to-back ordering of layers onscreen. Higher values place this layer visually closer to the viewer than layers with lower values. This can affect the visibility of layers whose frame rectangles overlap.

Therefore, as it defaults to 0, and `UIViews` are just wrappers for `CALayers`, you can use a value of `-1` on your `shapeLayer` in order to have it drawn behind your other views.

For example:

```
shapeLayer.zPosition = -1
```

---

#### Side Note

Most of the time in Swift, you don't need to explicitly supply a type when defining a variable. You can just let Swift infer it. For example:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would see 2 options, an easy and a harder option.

1. Move the `UIImageView` to the front after drawing the line, effectively hiding the line behind the `UIImageView`.
2. Calculate the points at which you want the line to start and end and draw a line from these points instead of the centers.

Comment: Thanks for replay . Point 1 also helps to hide line on UIImageview.